# Compare 2 color histogram one of they loaded from txt file

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm trying to save color histograms of image in a txt file to load them in other scripts.

Here is how I save them using `numpy`:

```
imgx = cv2.imread('pruebas/pop.png')
imgx = cv2.cvtColor(imgx,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
histr_hx = cv2.calcHist([imgx],[0],None,[180],[0,179])
np.savetxt('h_hist.txt', histr_hx)
```

Here is how I load it with `numpy` too:

```
txtHist = np.loadtxt('h_hist.txt', ndmin=2)
```

I think it's all ok, because when I print histr_hx and txtHist, both have the same structure, appearance and type.

The problem is when I want to use this loaded histogram and compare it with a new one using `cv2.compareHist()`, then appears the following error:

```
> zh = cv2.compareHist(textHist,new_hist,cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1534379934306\work\modules\imgproc\src\histogram.cpp:1935: error: (-215:Assertion failed) H1.type() == H2.type() && H1.depth() == 5 in function 
'cv::compareHist'
```

Both histograms are with the same structure, number of bins, etc. I don't understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your loaded array is of type `float64` whereas the calculated array is `float32`, which `cv2.compareHist()` does not like.

Is it important that you save the histograms as text files? Because you can also use `np.save` and `np.load` to save the arrays as [numpy binary files](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html#:~:text=npy%20format%20is%20the%20standard,machine%20with%20a%20different%20architecture.), which also save the `dtype` of the data. With this the code would look like this:

```py
imgx = cv2.imread('pruebas/pop.png')
imgx = cv2.cvtColor(imgx,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
histr_hx = cv2.calcHist([imgx],[0],None,[180],[0,179])
np.save('h_hist.npy', histr_hx)

txtHist = np.load('h_hist.npy')

cv2.compareHist(histr_hx, txtHist, cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)
```

If the text representation is important, you can convert the loaded data to the datatype of `histr_hx`:

```py
cv2.compareHist(histr_hx, txtHist.astype(histr_hx.dtype), cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)
```